# Custom database alert - Can it be done?

Tags: sql-server

I have this neat little query which let me know any ongoing query that stuck running for more than 3 minutes.

```
SELECT 
sqltext.TEXT,
s.session_id, r.status,
r.total_elapsed_time, r.cpu_time, r.wait_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections c ON s.session_id = c.session_id 
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r ON s.session_id = r.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
WHERE s.is_user_process = 1 
AND s.session_id <> @@SPID AND r.total_elapsed_time > 300000000
```

I came across this [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/create-configure-sql-server-agent-alerts/) that show how to set up SQL agent alert and send as notification.  Can I combine with my query so it sends alert email when I have query running longer than 3 minutes?

Comment: Is this what you really want?  Many queries, particularly reporting, take more than three minutes. Are you prepared to get emails or pages 24 hours a day? What will you do when you get this email?  Kill the session?

Comment: Hi Kevin,   The three minutes is just my own use of the example.  I can certainly increase it to 10 minutes to track the longer running one.  Our database often does not have many query that would take minutes to run.  Ideally in the past when this happens i find the slow query one, kill it and force the query store to use the quicker query plan if I find it appropriate.

Comment: Easiest way is to set it up as a SQL Agent job, and thrown an error if rows are returned by the query.  Set the job notification up to send email on failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do this is to create a SQL Agent job with a step that runs the following code:

```
<Your SELECT statement>
IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Long-running query detected!', 11, 1 )
    END
```

Configure notification on the job to send an email on failure, and if any rows are returned by the query, you'll get an email that the job failed.

Instead of setting up the job failure notification, you could set up a SQL Agent alert on the error that is raised as in the article you referenced.  But if the job notification is adequate it's less work to set up.